# launchAndWaitForRegister failed Timeout expired while starting chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

**I'm using docker swarm mode to setup 4 vp nodes.   The docker service scripts look like below:**

`docker service create --name vp0 --replicas 1 --network over \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    --mount type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock,ro=false \
    --env CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 \
    --env CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true \
    --env CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug \
    --env CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=dev \
    --env CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
    --env CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=pbft \
    --env CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_N=4 \
    --env CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_MODE=batch \
    --env CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_BROADCAST=20s \
    --env CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_REQUEST=60s \
    --env CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_RESENDVIEWCHANGE=120s \
    --env CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_VIEWCHANGE=60s \
    --env CORE_REST_ENABLED=false \
    --env CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=600000 \
    --env CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=600000 \
    ibmblockchain/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview peer node start`

**It seems that the network works fine after starting 4 services(vp0,vp1,vp2,vp3). But, when I was trying to deploy a chaincode example, I got this error after 10mins:**

[image]

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: did you managed to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hypothesis**

Your startup timeout value is misconfigured, so fabric defaults this to 5 seconds, which is too short for your deployment.

**Reasoning**

If it's really failing after a few seconds (~5?), then it suggests that your `CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=600000` isn't being honored.  Default core.yaml value is 300000, which is still longer than a few seconds.

If absent from both ENV and core.yaml, fabric defaults the value to 5 seconds.

If it takes longer than 5 seconds to get the REGISTER - then getting to the bottom of why this setting isn't making it to your peer process may fix your problem.

**How to confirm**

Ensure debug logging is enabled, and you should see `could not retrive timeout var...setting to 5secs` in the peer log when it starts.  (with the spelling errors)

**Source**

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v0.6/peer/node/start.go#L259

Comment: Well, I didn't find the message of "could not retrive timeout...".  I think the "CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=600000" has been applied.

Comment: How many seconds does it take? (Is it 5-10 minutes?).   An observation is that it's not using logger.debug to print that message - just fmt.printf.  I'm not sure where that would actually go in this case.

Comment: It was about 10 mins.

Comment: Ah ok.  I'd suggest updating the "after a few seconds" above to 10 minutes.  This seems like you're not getting the REGISTERED events for some reason.  I think these arrive over port 7053, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the mistake. I have updated that, thank u so much! BTW, is  it possible that this issue was caused by the  overlay network ?

Comment: That is likely.  What I'd suggest is attach to the docker containers and ensure one can communicate over port 7053 between the chaincode docker container and parent peer.  One can also try a docker logs -f on the chaincode container that gets created.  (might be failing pre-registration message for a different reason)

Comment: The truth is the chaincode container was not created.

Comment: Ha! That would do it.  If you're doing with with straight-up docker/swarm, I had to patch the base-image with the hyperledger codebase (including core.yaml) to get it to work.  (it tries to pull tag :latest...which of course doesn't exist)

Comment: I can make sure the hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest does exits. I used the “docker tag” command to create that. BTW, I'm using the images from ibmblockchain repo, the address is "https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmblockchain/fabric-peer/".

Comment: @steven-landers at my case CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT hasn't been aplied how to fix this ?

Comment: @steven-landers Thanks increasing CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=600000 really worked instantiating the chaincode quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

For Fabric v1.1, the correct format for the chaincode timeout line is:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=240s
```

the `s` defines the value as 240 seconds.
Testing this in the FABCAR app, the timeout changed as expected to 4 minutes